# Vuex: How to grab latest user data after user profile updated?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**I am using Vuex and having trouble getting a user's data to be "reactive" after his profile has been updated.** Here's my scenario:

> My `App.vue` checks a user's properties during the `created()` hook
>   like so:

```
  async created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('getSSOUser') // gets user from auth server
    await this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfiles') // queries known user table to see if user has a profile
    // set for global user state throughout app
    await this.setUser()
// then loads the UI
    this.isBusy = false
```

```
  methods: {
    setUser() {
      const user = this.getUserProfileBySSOID(this.ssoUser.data.user_id)
      this.$store.commit('SET_USER', user)
    }
```

So now I have the user's profile (`user` object) to use throughout the app. Works good....but...when a user edits his profile in the app (for example, updates his phone number, etc) and clicks submit, I can't seem to get the state to refresh/see that there has been a change unless the user manually refreshes the page.

What is the recommended way to handle this issue? Do I need to run a dispatch to the user state on every route change? The user's profile is located at `path: '/userEdit/:uid'`

> This is my app structure:

```
<div id="app">
    <Banner />
    <section class="container-fluid">
      <loading-spinner v-if="isBusy"></loading-spinner>
      <div v-else>
        <AuthName class="text-right" />
        <MainNav />
        <main id="routerView">
          <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
            <RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" />
          </transition>
        </main>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

User profile update function:

```
  ApiService.putUserProfile(this.user)
    .then(() => {
      this.loading = false
      this.$router.push('/admin/users')
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.response) {
        this.errors = err.response.data
      } else {
        if (err.request) {
          this.errors = err.request
        } else {
          this.errors = err.message
        }
      }
      this.loading = false
      console.error('Error from update', err)
    })
```

Comment: Would need to see your update functionality to answer that. If you've got the users information that's fine but something must be wrong with how their information is being altered. Do you post to a database for this or just update the store?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights: Added update function. I post to a database thanks!

Comment: Could you post ```ApiService```?

Answer (score 0):

after you update the detail of the user you can fire an event which may will fetch the data from the server behind the scene.

```
methods:{
loadData(){
         await this.$store.dispatch('getSSOUser') ;
         await this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfiles');
         await this.setUser()
         this.isBusy = false
          },
updateInfo() {
                this.form.put('api/profile').then((response) => {
                let userData = response.data.userdata;
                Fire.$emit('ProfileEvent');
            }
           },
  },
created(){
        this.loadData();
        Fire.$on('ProfileEvent', () => {
        this.loadData();
        });
       }
```

may be firing an event after the there is any changes saved in the profile page and executing the function that is called when the component is created after the fired event may resolve your problem. Hope you will get the idea from above code example.